# Possible Virus? Link at the bottom of some messages

Tags: sms, virus

My friend is getting this Chinese writing at the bottom of the odd sent text message, only on very few texts. It seems to be a link to a website something like 11.am. I have used AVG, Malwarebytes and Kaspersky, and they didn't find anything.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a website. It goes to a chinese casino webpage (or something like that). Anyway, because the text `11.am` is written like that, without a space between the dot and `a`, it looks to see if it is a link, and since it is a valid link, it processes it as so.